# Разница между вызовом события из браузера и из кода

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events, event-loop

До недавного времени я думал, что при вызове события из кода, происходит ровно то же самое что и при вызове события из браузера. Оказалось это вообще не так, просто в большинстве случаев мы не сталкиваемся с этой разницей

Для примера запустите код ниже и внимательно смотрите за очередью вывода сообщений в консоли:

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');

button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.clear();
  
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Microtask 1'));
  console.log('Task 1');
});

button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Microtask 2'));
  console.log('Task 2');
});

button2.addEventListener('click', () => button1.click());
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click to trigger "click" event</button>
<button id="button2">Click to see how JS triggers the "click" event</button>
```

Почему при вызове события при нажатии на кнопку физически порядок таков `Task 1, Microtask 1, Task 2, Microtask 2`, а при вызове события из кода порядок таков `Task 1, Task 2, Microtask 1, Microtask 2`?

Comment: тут лучше стоит обратить внимание на первый параметр обработчика в этих двух случаях

Comment: @Grundy Всмысле это работает только с `click` имеешь ввиду? Я не очень понял тебя

Comment: Нет, значения будут отличаться и всегда можно понять сработало ли событие из кода либо от действий пользователя

Comment: @Grundy А, ты про [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)? Если да, то, конечно, можно так. Но суть вопроса была не в том чтобы как различить было ли вызвано событие через код или пользователем, а в том что они по разному отрабатывают, когда событие вызывает пользователь и когда событие вызывается из кода :)

Comment: Но отрабатывают же они одинаково. _ты про Event.isTrusted?_ - и про него тоже, остальные свойства тоже отличаются

Comment: @Grundy "Но отрабатывают же они одинаково" - В основном да, т.к. чаще всего внтури слушателей что-то синхронное. Да даже если что-то асинхронное, то мы не обращаем внимание на порядок отработки. А он отличается в зависимотсти от того, событие вызвал пользователь или через код было вызывано событие

Answer (score 3):

Думаю из содержания выводимых сообщений опытные разработчики уже поняли в чём дело :)

---

Перед тем как дальше читать важно знать:

- [Микрозадачи](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide) выполняются после выхода из создавшей их функции или программы и только в том случае, если [стэк выполнения JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#stack) пуст, но перед возвратом управления [циклу событий](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop), используемому [пользовательским агентом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) для управления средой выполнения сценария

  Например [промис](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-ы используют [очередь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#queue) микрозадач для выполнения своих [колбэк-функций](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
- Новая задача кладётся в стэк выполнения, только после того как отрабатывают все микрозадачи предыдущей задачи. Потому если какая-та задача или микрозадача генерирует бесконечное количество микрозадач (например с помощью [queueMicrotask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask)), то следующая задача не выполнится никогда

---

Про объявление переменных рассказывать не буду, т.к. к сути вопроса не имеет отношения. Также не буду рассказывать про слушателя кнопки `button2` т.к. он просто нужен чтобы в желаемое время вызвать `button1.click()` и `console.clear()` т.к. он просто нужен чтобы не засорять консоль

### Общее для обоих методов:

1. `button1.addEventListener(/*1*/)` - добавляется первый слушатель на кнопку `button1`
2. `button1.addEventListener(/*2*/)` - добавляется второй слушатель на кнопку `button1`

### Клик на кнопку физически

1. Вызывается первый слушатель:

   1.1. Вызывается первая колбэк-функция - в стэк выполнения ставится первая колбэк-функция

   1.2. `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Microtask 1'))` - в очередь микрозадач ставится новая микрозадача `console.log('Microtask 1')`

   1.3. `console.log('Task 1')` - в стэк выполнения ставится новая задача

   1.4. Т.к. в первой колбэк-функции больше ничего нет, то в стэке выполняется, то что там лежит в обратном порядке. Последнее что мы туда положили - `console.log('Task 1')`, а значит он и выполнится и мы в консоли увидим `Task 1`. После выполнения она убирается из стэка выполнения

   1.5. Теперь в стэке осталась первая колбэк-функция, но т.к. ей больше нечего делать, то она заканчивает свою работу и убирается из стэка выполнения

   1.6. Наконец стэк выполнения становится пустым и начинают выполняться микрозадачи. Там одна микрозадача - `console.log('Microtask 1')`, после его выполнения мы увидим `Microtask 1`
2. Т.к. теперь очередь микрозадач пустой, то вызывается второй слушатель:

   2.1. Вызывается вторая колбэк-функция - в стэк выполнения ставится вторая колбэк-функция

   2.2. `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Microtask 2'))` - в очередь микрозадач ставится новая микрозадача `console.log('Microtask 2')`

   2.3. `console.log('Task 2')` - в стэк выполнения ставится новая задача

   2.4. Т.к. в первой колбэк-функции больше ничего нет, то в стэке выполняется, то что там лежит в обратном порядке. Последнее что мы туда положили - `console.log('Task 2')`, а значит он и выполнится и мы в консоли увидим `Task 2`. После выполнения она убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.5. Теперь в стэке осталась первая колбэк-функция, но т.к. ей больше нечего делать, то она заканчивает свою работу и убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.6. Наконец стэк выполнения становится пустым и начинают выполняться микрозадачи. Там одна микрозадача - `console.log('Microtask 2')`, после его выполнения мы увидим `Microtask 2`

Теперь мы явно увидели почему порядок вывода при клике физически таков `Task 1, Microtask 1, Task 2, Microtask 2`

### Клик на кнопку из кода

1. Вызывается `button1.click()` - в стэк выполнения ставится `button1.click()`
2. Вызывается первый слушатель:

   2.1. Вызывается первая колбэк-функция - в стэк выполнения ставится первая колбэк-функция

   2.2. `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Microtask 1'))` - в очередь микрозадач ставится новая микрозадача `console.log('Microtask 1')`

   2.3. `console.log('Task 1')` - в стэк выполнения ставится новая задача

   2.4. Т.к. в первой колбэк-функции больше ничего нет, то в стэке выполняется, то что там лежит в обратном порядке. Последнее что мы туда положили - `console.log('Task 1')`, а значит он и выполнится и мы в консоли увидим `Task 1`. После выполнения она убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.5. Далее на очереди первая колбэк-функция, но т.к. ей больше нечего делать, то она заканчивает свою работу и убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.6. **И вот ключевой момент** - наш стэк выполнения **не** пуст, там всё ещё осталась невыполненная функция `button1.click()`. Когда очередь доходит до него, то он продолжает свою работу
3. Вызывается второй слушатель:

   2.1. Вызывается вторая колбэк-функция - в стэк выполнения ставится вторая колбэк-функция

   2.2. `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('Microtask 2'))` - в очередь микрозадач ставится новая микрозадача `console.log('Microtask 2')`. Теперь у нас в очереди микрозадач 2 микрозадачи - `console.log('Microtask 1')` и `console.log('Microtask 2')`

   2.3. `console.log('Task 2')` - в стэк выполнения ставится новая задача

   2.4. Т.к. в первой колбэк-функции больше ничего нет, то в стэке выполняется, то что там лежит в обратном порядке. Последнее что мы туда положили - `console.log('Task 2')`, а значит он и выполнится и мы в консоли увидим `Task 2`. После выполнения она убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.5. Теперь в стэке осталась первая колбэк-функция, но т.к. ей больше нечего делать, то она заканчивает свою работу и убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.6. Очередь доходит до `button1.click()` и вот теперь то он и завершает свою работу, вызвав всех слушателей и убирается из стэка выполнения

   2.7. Наконец стэк выполнения становится пустым и начинают выполняться микрозадачи. Т.к. это очередь, а не стэк, то выполняются микрозадачи по очереди. Первым на очереди у нас `console.log('Microtask 1')`, а значит мы увидим `Microtask 1`

   2.8. Вторым на очереди у нас `console.log('Microtask 2')`, а значит мы увидим `Microtask 2`

Теперь мы явно увидели почему порядок вывода при клике на кнопку из кода таков `Task 1, Task 2, Microtask 1, Microtask 2`